# How can a stub and_raise an exception only once?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I know that there is a way to have a stub return multiple different values like this:

```
subject.stub(:method_call.and_return(1,2,3)
```

But I was hoping something like this would be possible:

```
subject.stub(:method_call).and_raise(Exception).once
subject.stub(:method_call).and_return(1)
```

But I haven't found an elegant way to have the stub only raise an exception the first time it's called.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this is with a counter variable like this:

```
counter = 0
times   = 2
TestModel.any_instance.stub(:some_method) do
  (counter += 1) <= times ? raise(Exception) : 1
end
```

Which will output like this:

```
test = TestModel.new
test.some_method
=> Exception
test.some_method
=> Exception
test.some_method
=> 1
```